# NoMethodError at /users undefined method `email` for #<User:0x007f64aa0033c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I wanted to use devise gem to do the user sign up module. I followed the instructions on the official devise website. And I changed the email field name to "contact". My test of the sign up module now receives the error:

```
NoMethodError at /users undefined method `email` for #<User:0x007f64aa0033c0>
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contact %>
    <div class="ui action input">
    <%= f.email_field :contact, class: "verification-contact", require: true %>
    <a class="ui button verification-button">Get Code</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At which line you got that error?

Comment: @Pavan `match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super` in method_missingactivemodel (4.2.4) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use any other field then email follow this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address)

Just changing name of email to contact may not help . Devise offers full support for customization , But it has to be step-to-step